# Showing Solutions of the Questions "separately"

Tags: tex-core, environments, exam

There is a class for LaTeX called `exam`. Using this class, one can write questions and answers for exams. The answers are displayed under (after) each question. My goal is to have all answers in the separate part of the document (after all questions). For that purpose I tried to create new environment like this:

```
\newenvironment{answer}{\def\answertext\begingroup}{\endgroup}
```

I was hoping to gather answer text into `\answertext` and dump it after all
questions. I'm sure, a solid TeX Package/Class writer can do it within no time... Please, give me some hint.

Answer (score 9):

We accumulate all the answers in a `\vbox`, and then dump the contents out of the `\vbox` and onto the page when it's appropriate.  (Thus, when the answers actually hit the page, they're not inside of the `\vbox`, and so there's no interference with pagebreaks.)

Here's a complete LaTeX file that demonstrates the idea:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\vbox{}

\newenvironment{answer}
{%
  \global\setbox\allanswers=\vbox\bgroup
  \unvbox\allanswers
}%
{%
  \bigbreak
  \egroup
}

\newcommand{\showallanswers}{\par\unvbox\allanswers}


%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question Why is there air?

  \begin{answer}
    Answer to Question \thequestion:

    There's air so that we can blow up volleyballs and basketballs.
  \end{answer}

  \question Who's buried in Grant's tomb?
  \begin{answer}
    Answer to Question \thequestion:

    What's his name.
  \end{answer}

  \question What was the color of George Washington's white horse?
  \begin{answer}
    Answer to Question \thequestion:

    Blue.  (No; Yellow!!)
  \end{answer}
\end{questions}

\bigskip
\begin{center}
  Here are the answers:
\end{center}
\showallanswers







\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 This is great. Does the `exam` class have something built-in like this for multiple choice questions (using the `choices` environment), or should I use something like your answer?

Comment: @cmhughes: Alas, no, this isn't part of the exam class,but you can just copy the code above into your LaTex file.

Comment: I try Phil Hirschhorn's method, and I found that I can use the `verbatim` environment inside the `answer` environment, great! I will try to hook your `solution` environment in the `exam` class to see whether I can put all the answers together separately. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. This works great; I notice that when you print all the answers they don't have the problem number to which they correspond. I tried fixing this with `etootlbox', but can't see to make it work: `\AtBeginEnvironment{answer}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\thequestion\,} ` prints the counter just after the question (which makes a lot of sense), but I cannot figure out how to print that counter on the box you defined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The `\def` macro doesn't accept `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` instead of `{ }`.
No macro does. Some macros (like `\hbox`) accept `\bgroup` and `\egroup` which are *implicit braces*, i.e. created using `\let\bgroup={` and `\let\egroup=}` (the `=` is optional).

To store the content of an environment use the `environ` package which was created for this purpose. The content is presented as `\BODY` which can be copied to `\answertext`. Keep in mind that the code is executed inside the environment, i.e. in a group, therefore `\global\let\answertext\BODY` or `\xdef\answertext{\BODY}` must be used. However, this only allows one answer text to be stored. If you want to accumulate answers use either `\g@addto@macro<macro>{<code>}`, e.g. `\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\answertext\expandafter{\BODY}` or the `\xappto` macro of the `etoolbox` package.

Some example (without the `exam` class):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\answertext}{}
\NewEnviron{answer}{\global\let\answertext\BODY}
% or
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{answer}{\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\answertext\expandafter{\BODY}}%
\makeatother
% or
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\NewEnviron{answer}{\xappto\answertext{\expandonce{\BODY}}}%


\begin{document}

The question
\begin{answer}
  The answer text
\end{answer}

\newpage
% Some time later
\answertext


\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the intention is also to *add* to `\answertext` (e.g. via `\g@addto@macro`)

Comment: @Caramdir: Good point. I forgot to point out that this only works for one answer. I will add the use of `\g@addto@macro`.

Comment: Hi, great answer. In my usage, I have some code snippets in the answers, so I use a `verbatim` environment inside the answer environment, but I get failed. I'm using the third way which use `\xappto` command which add the answer body to a macro definition. Are there any workaround about this issue. I know that `verbatim` environment is some kind of fragile, which means I can't move its body simply or pass its body as macro arguments. Thanks.

Comment: @ollydbg23: In your case it would be better to store the answer in a savebox and set this box later. Search for "savebox" to find some suitable solutions. However, this way the format of the answer is getting defined by the active format when it is stored not when it is placed, like in the case above.

Answer (score 0):

My file ans.sty at http://www.cwru.edu/artsci/math/wells/pub/mytex.html is old but I use it regularly to this day.  It can no doubt be modified to do what you want.