# How to put different parts of text to a other page

Tags: formatting

I would like to take out some part of my document and put them all together at the end of my document without doing it manually. Is there a command to do that?

example :
blabla bla//
Exercice1//
bla bla bla//
Exercice2//

And I would like to put all the exercice parts on a different page.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question and provide the code for a small document (`\documentclass... \end{document`) which we can compile to understand the context and what you are trying to do. It is not at all clear from the example you've given what syntax you hope to use and we don't know anything about the environment or document class, so it is not very easy to give effective help.

Comment: "Put at the end a part"  mean for you copying  (print where it is and again at the end of the document) of or only move/translate  (print only at the end)? ?

Comment: The answers package will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer: [Showing Solutions of the Questions "separately"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/showing-solutions-of-the-questions-separately/15354#15354).  It's for collecting solutions to exercises to be printed later in the document, but it makes no use of the exam documentclass.  It might be what you want.